# Pyspark: how to append value to the beginning of a column?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe. For column 1 (which contains numbers), I need to add a `9` to the beginning value to every row.

Current state

```
col1
----
123  
456
```

Future state

```
col1
----
9123  
9456
```

I am able to pull up the column `df.select("col1").show()`. However I dont know if I am going about it the right way. I know pyspark dataframes are immutable. Should I NOT be doing a select to begin with?

Comment: why not just add 9000 to your numbers?

Comment: that just dummy data i added.. I cant add 9000.  I just need to know how to append a number to the front of the column.

Comment: You can create a new column using `df.withColumn` and either use `concat()` or a udf (User Defined Function). You then drop the column with the old results. See this [link](https://hackingandslacking.com/dataframe-transformations-in-pyspark-continued-907b1e870442) for concat use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sdf = sc.parallelize([[123], [456]]).toDF(["col1"])
sdf.show()

+----+
|col1|
+----+
| 123|
| 456|
+----+

sdf.withColumn("col2", sf.concat(sf.lit("9"), sf.col("col1").cast("string")).cast("int")).show()

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
| 123|9123|
| 456|9456|
+----+----+
```